# How to swap characters in a string

Tags: c#

You are going to tell me this is easy, I know, but how do I simultaneously change all A into B, and all B into A, in a string, s.

```
s= s.Replace( 'A', 'B').Replace( 'B', 'A');
```

clearly doesn't quite work, so what is the right way?

Comment: Write your own `for` loop.

Comment: If you can find a character that will not be in the string you can simply insert one intermediate replace!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use linq to replace the characters:

```
string s = "ABZBA";
var result= s.Select(x=> x == 'A' ? 'B' : (x=='B' ? 'A' : x)).ToArray();
s = new String(result);
```

### Output:

> > BAZAB

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) and a `MatchEvaluator` to do the job.  This will cope with strings longer than single characters, if `A` and `B` ever get more complex:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "A|B", (m) => m.Value == "A" ? "B" : "A");
```

Answer (score 3):

Copying the string into `StringBuilder` and doing replacements character-by-character is one way of achieving this:

```
var s = new StringBuilder(originalString);
for (int i = 0 ; i != s.Length ; i++) {
    var ch = s.Characters[i];
    if (ch == 'A') { s.Characters[i] = 'B'; }
    else if (ch == 'B') { s.Characters[i] = 'A'; }
}
originalString = s.ToString();
```

If you wish to use `Replace`, and there is a character that is guaranteed to be absent from your string, you could do it in the same way that you do swaps with a temporary variable:

```
s= s.Replace( 'A', '~').Replace( 'B', 'A').Replace( '~', 'B');
```

The above assumes that `~` is not present in the original string.

Comment: yeah, that seems familiar :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the characters of `s` and if you find `A` put `B` (and vice-versa).

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
foreach(var ch in s)
{
    if (ch == 'A') newString.Append('B');
    else if (ch == 'B') newString.Append('A');
    else newString.Append(ch);
}

s = newString.ToString();
```

Comment: Optimization: `newstring = new StringBuilder(s.Length)`, which creates a string builder buffer of exactly the right size.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
string s = "ABABAB";
char placeholder = '~';

//After this s is BABABA
s = s.Replace('A', placeholder).Replace('B', 'A').Replace(placeholder, 'B');
```

Comment: I like your choice of placeholder a lot :-)

Comment: Too bad if s already contains the placeholder...

Answer (score 2):

A solution to your problem could be this:

```
 string s = "AABB";
 var dict = new Dictionary<char, char> {{'A', 'B'}, {'B', 'A'}};

 s = new string(s.Select(c => dict.ContainsKey(c) ? dict[c] : c).ToArray());
```

This way you can replace all the characters that you want, just add the key/value pair to the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this extension method:

```
string Swap( this string s, char a, char b, char unused)
{
    return s.Replace( a, unused).Replace( b, a).Replace( unused, b);
}
```

Then I changed it to:

```
string Swap( this string s, char a, char b)
{
    return new string( s.Select( ch => (ch == a) ? b :(ch == b) ? a : ch).ToArray());
}
```